# How to convert a datetime + timezone string to POSIXct/POSIXt with tzone attribute?

Tags: r, string, datetime, timezone, lubridate

What would be a "canonical" way using `{lubridate}` package to convert a date-time + timezone from *character* to *POSIXct/POSIXt* while preserving the timezone into the `tzone` attribute?

### Example

I'm given `my_time_string`:

```r
my_time_string <- "2023-02-01 19:16:24 UTC"
class(my_time_string)
#> [1] "character"
attributes(my_time_string)
#> NULL
```

And I want to convert it to `my_time_dttm`:

```r
my_time_dttm <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2023-02-01 19:16:24", tz = "UTC")
class(my_time_dttm)
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
attributes(my_time_dttm)
#> $class
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
#> 
#> $tzone
#> [1] "UTC"
```

Is there an out-of-the-box function/method, or do I must substring the original first, to extract the timezone?

Comment: If you have different time zones, all will be converted to one time zone. No two dates of different time zones can be stored in a vector. So either use sapply to loop over changing the time zone for each.

Comment: Thanks! Good point, I didn't think about that. So let's assume the case is that all data in the vector is strings of date-time + same tz. Could you show an example of converting the entire vector's class to _POSIXct/POSIXt_ while passing the timezone from the string into the `tzone` attribute?

Comment: R mostly recognizes the Olson time format. ie timezone specified in the region/city format. Note that there is no standardized notations for things like CET, EAT, EST etc.. though a few are generally agreed upon. Take for example the time zone abbreviation "IST". It can refer to Irish Summer Time, Israel Standard Time or Indian Summer Time all of which observe different time zones.. So only the Olson format is generally accepted. So yes, if your string has that, it is easily dealt with. Otherwise you've to manually determine the TZ, unless the tz is commonly agreed upon abbr. eg GMT, UTC

Answer (score 1):

You can store these datetimes in a list construction:

```
c(
"2023-02-01 19:16:24 UTC",
"2023-02-02 19:16:24 GMT") %>% 
  as.list %>% 
  lapply(\(x) lubridate::ymd_hms(x, tz=str_extract(x, "\\b[:alpha:]+\\z"))) # or other regex if required
```

It will result into:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2023-02-01 19:16:24 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2023-02-02 19:16:24 GMT"
```

with the following structure:

```
List of 2
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-02-01 19:16:24"
 $ : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-02-02 19:16:24"
```

After all you can convert all the dates to the single tz for instance adding another line:

```
... %>% 
  lapply(\(x) lubridate::force_tz(x, tz="UTC"))
```

that will give you:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2023-02-01 19:16:24 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2023-02-02 19:16:24 UTC"
```

Comment: This is generally not a good idea. Eg try Kuwait time with the time zone EAT, or los angeles time with time zone PST, or even Israel with TZ of IST.. most would fail before parsing. Better use the olson TZ format

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you for the valuable comment. Let's see the OP response as tz is OS specific and we have no information about OP's dataset details.